# While loop code output

Tags: java, while-loop

```
 int x = 13; 
 while(x >= 4) { 
 if (x % 2 == 1) { 
 System.out.println(x); 
 } 

 x = x - 3; 
 }
```

I know the output of this, it is 13 and 7, would someone care to explain as how it came to be 13 and 7.

Comment: Do you know what `%` means? It's the [modulus operator](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/modulus.html). To find out what the program does, follow the steps in your head, and write on a piece of paper what happens on each step.

Comment: what's wrong with it, it is working fine,
first it';; check for 13 and prints it, then for 10, and then for 7 and prints it and then for 4

Comment: Substitute the value 13, 10 and so on for x . Now follow the statements and what it prints in your notebook.

Comment: i believe the % finds the reminder if i am correct. i understand where the 13 comes from but don't quite understand how it gives out a 7.

Comment: The `if` statement basically means: "if x is odd".

Comment: It prints a 7 for the same reason it prints out 13...the remainder of 7/2 is 1, just like 13/2.

Comment: I don't know why people are keep on putting such silly questions without efforts, and moreover others are explaining instead of providing solution for some one stuck with real efforts... 
@Philip:do some efforts...Even a techie kid can observe the flow.

Comment: @ShaileshSaxena answering to a less that acceptable question is timepass. best way to kill some boring mins:-)

Comment: @kOUSHIK: But just think about the person, googling about some serious issues, and opens such links with hope to get something useful, and finally.....Moreover it spoils the content policy of StackOverflow and not useful to any one. I suggest to simply down-vote and close such questions.

Comment: @ShaileshSaxena yes thats a serious consideration.!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`13 % 2 = 1` therefore, you print `13`. 
Now `x = 10`.
`10 % 2 = 0`, so you dont print out `10`.
Now `x = 7`.
`7 % 2 = 1`, so you print 7.
Now `x = 4`.
`4 % 2 = 0`;
Now `x = 1` and the loop stops.

The `%` operator is the modulo operator. This prints the remainder when dividing two numbers. For example `14/3 = 4 remainder 2`, so `13 % 4 = 2`.

Comment: Ahhhh i see , it was fairly simple, thanks for your answer will accept as soon as i can.

Answer (score 2):

First x is 13, is it >= then 4? Yes. Enter the while loop. Is 13%2==1. Yes. Print x (print 13). Then x = x-13, x becomes 10. Is 10 >=4? Yes. .... So on.

Answer (score 2):

What don't you understand?

At the first iteration, `x=13`, `13%2=1` so it prints `13`. The seconds iteration, `x=10` (`x=x-3`) `10%2=0`, nothing is printed. The third iteration `x=7` (`10-3`), `7%2=1` so 7 is printed.

After that, x=4 so nothing is printed and `x=1` quits the loop.

Answer (score 2):

case 1:

```
---> x = 13;
     while(true) //  13 >= 4
     if(true)    // 13%2 = 1 which is 1==1  is true
     then print x
     reduce x by 3 // now x ==10
```

case 2 :

```
---> x = 10;
     while(true) // 10 > =4
     if(false) // 10 % 2 = 0, 0 == 1 is false
     skip
     reduce x by 3// now x == 7
```

case 3:

```
---> x =7;
     while(true) // 7 > = 4
     if(true) //7 % 2 ,1==1 is true
     print x;
     reduce x by 3 // x == 4
```

case 4:

```
---> x =4;
     while(true) // 4 > = 4
     if(false) //4 % 2 ,0==1 is false
     skip
     reduce x by 3 // x == 4
```

case 5:

```
---> x =1;
     while(false) // 7 > = 4
     skip
```

operator summary :
    `**%** finds remainder`  // result is undefined if RHS operand is `0`
    `**>=** greater than or equals`